# Creating Forms dynamically depend upon the response from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I'm working on one app in which the UI rendering will depend upon the `JSON` sent by the server.

The server will decide UI components, I've actually created extended classes for the basic components like `UILabel`,`UITextField` etc, but this seems like very lengthy and complex process.

So now I am looking frameworks which can capable to do it. Since I am going to implement it in other apps too, it needs to be generic. Is there any other way to to do with it?

Comment: https://github.com/derekblair/ILPDFKit

Comment: @sweta.me i don't want to create PDF forms .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it out yourself, which would be simpler to implement and debug in case you have any problem. Using any already built framework/library will not provide you flexibility that you MIGHT need.

Consider that you have a function which parses the JSON and decide whether it's textfield/button/label/textview and so on... (It can be one of the attribute in fields array in response).

Make a custom model class say `Field`, in that class you can have all the details related to the field to be put on the screen; like X, Y, Width, Height, Numeric, Alphanumeric and so on... This all values needs to be parsed from JSON response that you get from API.

You can iterate them one by one like in following function:

```
- (void)setFieldOnScreen:(Field *)f { // Field is a model class that suits your requirement

    if (f.type isEqualToString:@"UITextField"]) {

        float x = f.x.floatValue;
        float y = f.y.floatValue;
        float width = f.width.floatValue;
        float height = f.height.floatValue;        

        UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
        txtField.delegate = self;
        txtField.font = f.font_name; // from repsonse
        txtField.tag = f.tag.integerValue; // from response
        txtField.textAlignment = f.alignment //NSTextAlignmentLeft or whatever from response

        // even you can fill up preset values in it from response
        txtField.text = f.presetvalue;

            ... and so on....

        } else if ... /// for UILabel/UIButton/UISwitch or any other subclass of the controls
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i have already done this part of creating models and  distinguishing it  from other components . Main problem here is delegation and events . in your example textfield is created locally we can not use it globally in case of  tableview  deque problem may raise .

Comment: Can you be more specific related to dequeuing problem. I didn't see any problem related to that. I also had the same situation when I needed to lay them out on the tableview. It worked pretty well. You can access them with tags.

Comment: Yes, you are right we can solve it by using tags . but handling get more complex.

Comment: Again, can you be specific about the complexity? I don't find any complexity dealing with this. BTW, when you use any third party library; it will also make things work this way. BUT, if something is missing in those libraries, or say some customisation that you need to make; ultimately you would be spending more time.

Comment: can you please tell me how it will work for multiple textfields , since i am getting horizontal and vertical positions as (0 , 1) . you can consider it as n*n matrix